# how to stop bootstrap nav bar from collapsing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

Hi I need some help on my Bootstrap3, when I'm using my desktop the navigation bar works totally fine. But once I try on my phone the nav bar just collapse **(It's width becomes smaller)** how do I solve it? 
My website is http://theboundlesstraveller.neocities.org/index.html 
Please advice...

UPDATE: Code snippet

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="mytripjournals.html">My Trip Journals</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="busy-Peeps.html">Busy-Peeps</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="lifestyle.html">Lifestyle</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perhaps provide some code here in your post?

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to do something like this

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>    
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#itemonelink">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#itemtwolink">Item Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#signuplink">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#loginlink">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qo046pfk/)

Comment: Hi sorry, this is my code! <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mytripjournals.html">My Trip Journals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="busy-Peeps.html">Busy-Peeps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lifestyle.html">Lifestyle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

Comment: I want it to stay as the desktop version without shortening of the nav bar. As for now, when I use my mobile to enter the web, my nav bar becomes shorter...

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit.

Change `Brand` in `HTML` with your site name

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">    
          <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-left">Brand</div>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>   

      </div>
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
          <li><a href="mytripjournals.html">My Trip Journals</a></li> 
          <li><a href="busy-Peeps.html">Busy-Peeps</a></li> 
          <li><a href="lifestyle.html">Lifestyle</a></li> 
          <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a></li> 
        </ul> 
      </div> 
  </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .navbar-brand-left {
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        display: block;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```